# Adding map entries fails in program but works in interpreter

Tags: scala

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but this straightforward App doesn't work:

```
object runnable extends App {
   Test.calculate
}
object Test {
  val c = Map[Int, Int]()
  def calculate {
    c + ( 1 -> 2 )
  }
...
```

And set a break point in the debugger immediately following that line, the contents of the map are `Map()`

But if I do the equivalent in the repl:

```
val c = Map[Int,Int]()
c: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()
c+(1->2)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)
```

I've even tried making the map mutable in the App code but it doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: Add '=' to calculate `def calculate = `

Comment: I actually wanted to demonstrate that adding entries to the map doesn't work by using a Unit function.  I want to understand whether it's possible to effect an instance field as a side effect of a function call.  This test function isn't the actual code but it does emulate the behaviour I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the assignment to a new varibale after adding to the map:

```
val c1 = Map[Int, Int]()
val c2 = c1 + (1 -> 2)
println(c2) // Map(1 -> 2)

// using a var instead
var c = Map[Int, Int]()
c = c + (1 -> 2)
println(c)  // Map(1 -> 2)
```

You cannot change an instance of `scala.collection.Map` as it is **immutable**. If you want a **mutable** map you need to use `scala.collection.mutable.Map`:

```
val c = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]()
// the next three lines are differnt ways to add an element
c.put(1, 2)
c(1) = 2
c += 1 -> 2
println(c)  // Map(1 -> 2)
```

Comment: I thought that by using a class val it would hold state, as it would in Java.  Is that not the case?  It also doesn't work if I use a var at the class scope.  I was hoping to have this map constructed in a class instance and grab it from the runnable object.  Essentially following the same pattern you would use in Java.

Comment: OK, you might want a mutable map (I added a sample to the answer). But be aware that using immutable collections is preferred because it makes your code easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the docs, http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html, which implied a mutable map could have elements added without introducing a new reference.

@Sebastian is correct, it needs to be a var.  The working version looks like:

```
object runnable extends App {
   Test.calculate
}
object Test {
   var c = Map[Int, Int]()
   def calculate {
     c += ( 1 -> 2 )
   }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Think your code worked in interpreter because it immediately prints the result(in this case result of the function +).

That's why you get 2 distinct reponses(*c, res2*).

You should try to guess calculate function type.

it's not: *Void -> Void*

it is: *Void -> Map[Int, Int]*

I hope this may help you